# "Refused to apply style from {link} because its MIME type is not a supported and strict MIME checkinis enabled." in Vue+Vuetify App

Tags: gitlab, vuetify.js, mime-types

I created a **Vue+Vuetify** project using `vue-create-app`. In my local system **Vuetify** works fine but it doesn't work on **Gitlab live server**. And shows this error message in live app:

> "Refused to apply style from 'https://me.gitlab.io/css/chunk-vendors.16d7cb41.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled."

I deployed the app in **Gitlab** without modifying the boiler code of `vue-create-app`.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the problem is that the site is deployed at `https://me.gitlab.io/<project-name>/` but the generated index.html contains absolute paths e.g. `/css/chunk-vendors.16d7cb41.css`.

As [documentend here](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath), I solved by editing my `vue-config.js` to add:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/<project-name>/'
    : '/'
}
```